Is there an alternating power functor on braided monoidal categories?
Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a braided monoidal $\mathbb{C}$-linear category and $V\in \mathsf{C}$ any object. Then we can form the tensor power $V^{\otimes 2}$.
The braid group $B_2$ acts on $V^{\otimes 2}$, and we can consider the map
$$p : V^{\otimes 2} \to V^{\otimes 2}$$
given by
$$p= \frac{1}{2}(1 - b),$$
where $b$ the usual generator of $B_2$.
I want to call the cokernel of $1-p$ the alternating power $\bigwedge^2 V$ of $V$.
I have found literature where this is defined for at least some examples of $\mathsf{C}$ and particular choices of $V$. I do not see why this construction would fail to be functorial in general, but I am struggling to see what should I show.
Is there any place in the literature where this is defined?
If not, is there any reason why this could not possibly work?
(Remark: the first paragraph is essentially copied from  the n-lab page for exterior algebras and chaging "symmetric" for "braided.")

I'm not sure what your question is ? This will of course be functorial for functors which are braided and right exact. An issue with this definition is that it's not an idempotent though. You might find this paper interesting : Arkady Berenstein, Sebastian Zwicknagl, Braided Symmetric and Exterior Algebras (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504155) where they argue the version defined using a coboundary structure rather than a braiding  works better.

@Adrien Well, my question was motivated by some authors (e.g. Donkin in The q-Schur Algebra) choosing to define these only for certain choices of V, and some other authors (e.g. Mulmuley in GCT7 Section 3) seemingly needing to change the definition to avoid some problems. Also, the n-lab does not usually assume too much. Your comment answers my question, thanks.
